# gradle: compile android junit test apk file

Tags: java, android, junit, gradle

Can I compile Android JUnit test apk file by using gradle script? Now my test class is:

```
    public class main extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginWindow> {
        public main() {
        super("com.tecomgroup.handifox", LoginWindow.class);
        }
        ...
    }
```

and gradle says that he cannot find class LoginWindow. Should I add the LoginWindow.java to dependencies {} block? Will such test work? Or may be there is another way to compile test apk file?

Comment: The project structure in Gradle Android plugin  is different from Ant Android structure. Tests are within project in `src/test/java` directory, not in another project. Do you have tests in another project?

Comment: My application and junit test for it are two different projects (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: @user2172741 Then you have to add that project's jar as compiletest dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Gradle Android plugin, you no longer need to have a separate project for testing. Production sources should be put into `src/main/java` directory, test sources should be in `src/instrumentTest/java`. The same applies to resources.

From Android Gradle plugin User Guide on [project structure](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure).

> Project Structure
>
> The basic build files above expect a default folder structure. Gradle follows the concept of convention over configuration, providing sensible default option values when possible.
>
> The basic project starts with two components called “source sets”. The main source code and the test code. These live respectively in:
>
> ```
> src/main/
> src/instrumentTest/
> ```
>
> Inside each of these folders exists folder for each source components.
>   For both the Java and Android plugin, the location of the Java source code and the Java resources:
>
> ```
> java/
> resources/
> ```
>
> For the Android plugin, extra files and folders specific to Android:
>
> ```
> AndroidManifest.xml
> res/
> assets/
> aidl/
> rs/
> jni/
> ```
>
> Note: src/instrumentTest/AndroidManifest.xml is not needed as it is created automatically.

You can change the [standard project layout](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

```
sourceSets {
    instrumentTest {
        java {
            srcDir '../other/src/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir '../other/src/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that teamleader will accept such actions with source code. May be there is another way to compile test apk file? Or may be run it by some way with link to main project folder?

Comment: @user2172741 You can change the directory of test source files. Check the update. But remember 'convention over configuration'!

Comment: Grzegorz, the chapter "23.12.1. Test execution" says "Tests are executed in a separate JVM, isolated from the main build process.". As I understand, I can't run UI tests on device or emulator by this way, can I?

Comment: @user2172741 When your are compiling Android project you use android plugin that executes instrumented tests on emulator or device. It is different from standard Java plugin of Gradle. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basic-Project

Comment: thanks. Now I can build both project and test apk files (as you recommended, there is only one project with default folders), but I can not sign test apk file (so I can not test release version of project) and running tests says that there are 0 tests TBD

Comment: @VMaleev Make a new question for signing apk file.

Comment: Grzegorz, I've decided to use Maven to build an apk files. Now it works. Your tips were very useful, thanks!